# ShrinkWrap modifier not maintaining same offset for all vertices

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to use the Shrinkwrap modifier to connect two meshes, but I can't make it work properly on the cylinder. I tried to change the Shrinkwrap settings but I got nothing out of it.

The vertex (one in red) should be at green arrow, but I don't know why it's behaving in that way, is there a way to do it without manually changing the vertex ?[image]

Cylinder modifier

[image]

Comment: So, we're assuming that the modified object's Y is in the red-green direction, and the vertex marked with the red arrow is weight 1 in 'Group'  .. is that right?

Comment: Object's Y direction is in the red/green direction, and the entire loop is weight 1 in 'Group'.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe edit that in to make it absoulutely clear, and share the relevant chunk of your .blend on  https://blend-exchange.com/ ?